# Can you 'overload a cast' in C++ OOP?

Tags: c++, oop, casting, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

Well, the WinAPI has a `POINT` struct, but I am trying to make an alternative class to this so you can set the values of `x` and `y` from a constructor. This is hard to explain in one sentence.

```
/**
 * X-Y coordinates
 */
class Point {
  public:
    int X, Y;

    Point(void)            : X(0),    Y(0)    {}
    Point(int x, int y)    : X(x),    Y(y)    {}
    Point(const POINT& pt) : X(pt.x), Y(pt.y) {}

    Point& operator= (const POINT& other) {
        X = other.x;
        Y = other.y;
    }
};

// I have an assignment operator and copy constructor.
Point myPtA(3,7);
Point myPtB(8,5);

POINT pt;
pt.x = 9;
pt.y = 2;

// I can assign a 'POINT' to a 'Point'
myPtA = pt;

// But I also want to be able to assign a 'Point' to a 'POINT'
pt = myPtB;
```

Is it possible to overload `operator=` in a way so that I can assign a `Point` to a `POINT`? Or maybe some other method to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the job of a type conversion operator:

```
class Point {
  public:
    int X, Y;

    //...

    operator POINT() const {
        POINT pt;
        pt.x = X;
        pt.y = Y;
        return pt;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank You! I actually hadn't a clue there was a conversion operator. I guess it all comes down to what you don't know that you don't know, if that makes any sense ;)

Comment: You can also derive from the POINT struct or class.  This gives you an implicit cast to POINT& and the ability to turn a Point* into a POINT* implicitly.

Comment: What @Yakk suggest is what it actually done by ATL to provide a (bad) C++ wrapper around `VARIANT` and `BSTR`. For `CComSafeArray`, they used a conversion operator.

Answer (score 4):

You could add a cast operator to your `Point` class:

```
class Point {
  // as before
  ....
  operator POINT () const { 
    // build a POINT from this and return it
    POINT p = {X,Y};
    return p;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conversion operator:

```
class Point 
{
public:
   operator POINT()const
   {
       Point p;
       //copy data to p
       return p;
   }
};
```